# Return a list (inside an object) from myBatis (Java)

Tags: java, mybatis

I need some help here, I am trying to return a list of objects, inside a parent object using myBatis.

### THE PROBLEM :

Before you begin reading the code below - My error that I get back is :

```
SqlSession operation; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 4102
```

What is interesting here is that this somehow means I am hitting the stored procedure, seeing the amount of data there is, and erroring due to having too many results because myBatis thinks I am using selectOne() - Which is not true? I will add, that 4102 is the exact number of records in the table I am trying to pull this data from.

### MY CODE :

Here are the result maps for the parent and child objects :

```
<resultMap id="ParentObjectMap" type="com.company.product.mybatis.model.ParentObject">
    <collection property="children" resultMap="childrenMap"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="childrenMap" type="com.company.product.mybatis.model.ChildObject">
    <id column="ChildId" jdbcType="BIGINT" property="childId" />
    <result column="Name" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name" />
</resultMap>
```

Here is the code for each of the above maps.

```
public class ParentObject implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private List<ChildObject> childrenMap;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS EXCLUDED FOR BREVITY. */
}
```

And the class for the Child object :

```
public class ChildObject implements Serializable {

    private long childId;
    private String name;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS REMOVED FOR BREVITY. */
}
```

Here Is the Stored Procedure which I am calling, which aims to return the data :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.PR_Children_Get
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    SELECT 
        tp.ChildId,
        tp.Name
    FROM dbo.Children tp WITH (NOLOCK)
END
GO
```

And here is how I am executing that procedure in my mapper :

```
<select id="getChildren" resultMap="ParentObjectMap">
    exec [dbo].[PR_Children_Get]
</select>
```

Here is the interface through which I access my mapper :

```
@Override
public ParentObject getChildren() throws Exception {
    ParentObject result = ParentObjectMapper.getChildren();
    return result;
}
```

Here is the interface of that ParentObjectMapper :

```
/* Hiding imports for brevity */

public interface ParentObjectMapper {

    // Get the list children, the list should be a property within the parent object.
    ParentObject getChildren();
}
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Using an SQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you execute through a mapper interface and the method would be: `ParentObject getChildren();`  this explicitly expect a single result because this is not a collection type, then the error you got.

But I'm not telling you should change to `List<ParentObject> getChildren();` to avoid this error ... or maybe you should ... for a while, because it would help understanding the issue:

With your code Mybatis creates a new ParentObject for each result row because the parentId is never returned and Mybatis does not assume you have a single parent. Then the query shall return a parentId column and the *ParentObjectMap* start with `<id column="parentId" property="id"/>`, so that Mybatis knows how to group children by their parent.

Comment: Hi @blackwizard, I have added the code for my mapper interface and that should show how I am hitting the actual mapper XML - sorry for not including that originally, I thought I had! 

Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The call `ParentObject result = ParentObjectMapper.getChildren();` is misleading: it looks like a static call on an interface!?
I suppose this is just a typo and working code looks more like `ParentObject result = this.mapper.getChildren();`

Anyway, IMO, everything is in my answer: you need to select and map the parentId so that Mybatis can group children by parent, ... even though there is only one parent.

Comment: I am slightly confused about that - because what I am not getting the parent from the database, I am creating it at run time, then populating the list inside that - Would it be better if I just completely scrapped the parent object? Is there a way to just get the list back? Because I actually don't need there to be a parent... Thanks for your help on this so far :)

Comment: then `getChildren` should return `List<ChildObject>` and just `parent.setChildrenMap(childrenList)`;

Comment: Thankyou so much!! That gets me my data back!! You have been so helpful to me with myBatis on a couple of questions here now! Thanks again!